# Is there a better and shorter way to handle asynchron data?

Tags: angularjs

When I work with asynchron data I use the following way:

Service:

```
app.service("DashboardService", function( $resource, $q, APIService ) {

    return {
        getLatestDevices: getLatestDevices,
    }

    function getLatestDevices() {
        var d = $q.defer()
        APIService.query({route: 'devices'}).$promise.then(function(data) {
           d.resolve(data)
        })
        return d.promise
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("DashboardCtrl", function( $scope, DashboardService ) {

    DashboardService.getLatestDevices().then(function(data){
        $scope.latestDevices = data
    })

})
```

Is there a better or shorter way to do this? Or I do it in the right way?
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically that is what I do, too, but it looks like you are creating a superfluous promise.
This should work, too, I think:

```
function getLatestDevices() {
    return APIService.query({route: 'devices'}).$promise;
}
```

I don't get why you would want to unpack and repack that promise?!

One reason would be if you need to transform the data returned from APIService before returning it, but even then you could use implicit promise chaining:

```
function getLatestDevices() {
    return APIService.query({route: 'devices'}).$promise.then(function (data) {
       return someTransformFn(data);
    });
}
```

Calling then automatically creates a promise, that angularjs automatically resolves with the returned value.

Comment: Thank you! When I use you Code... I got the following error from my Controller: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: Ups...it was a return problem...i forgot the first return!